# Prolog: Matching elements in a specific between two lists

Tags: list, prolog, pattern-matching, match

I already have this code to match if any numbers in a list match any numbers in the other list. However, I need to modify my recursion so it returns false if the same number is found in the same position on both lists.

For example:

`[5,3,4,6,2]` is compatible with `[3,1,2,2,7]`; and `[1,3,4,9,2]` is incompatible with `[4,5,2,9,8]` because both lists have a 9 in the 4th position.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
common_elements([], L) :-
    fail.
common_elements([H|T], L) :-
    memberchk(H, L), !.
common_elements([H|T], L) :-
    common_elements(T, L).
```

SWI-Prolog example inputs and outputs for current code:

```
?- common_elements([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9]).
false.

?- common_elements([1,2,3,6],[6,7,8,9]).
true.
```

Comment: Do the two lists have to have the same length?

Comment: Do the list items have to be numbers?

Comment: If the lists are the same length, you can just do: `maplist(dif, L1, L2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with (nearly) all predicates with list processing, you can split your predicate in two types of clauses:

- *base clauses*: in many cases these lists deal with empty lists. Here this is for instance:

  ```
  compatible([],_).
  compatible(_,[]).
  ```
- *inductive clauses*: in this case both lists are not empty. In that case you have to compare the *head*s of the two lists. If not equal, you make a recursive call:

  ```
  compatible([HA|TA],[HB|TB]) :-
      HA \= HB,
      compatible(TA,TB).
  ```

  in the recursive call, you simply use the *tail*s of both lists.

Now merging both clauses:

```
compatible([],_).
compatible(_,[]).
compatible([HA|TA],[HB|TB]) :-
    HA \= HB,
    compatible(TA,TB).
```

You can make it a bit more effecient (and atomic by using a cut):

```
compatible([],_) :-
    !.
compatible(_,[]).
compatible([HA|TA],[HB|TB]) :-
    HA \= HB,
    compatible(TA,TB).
```

**Demo (`swipl`)**:

```
?- compatible([5,3,4,6,2],[3,1,2,2,7]).
true.

?- compatible([1,3,4,9,2],[4,5,2,9,8]).
false.
```